# ObservableCollection size changes after leaving a session

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observablecollection that is bound to a listbox that displays strings received from the network. since the data received everyday is huge, i managed to limit the size of the collection. Each time it gets to the given max size, it removes the bottom item befor adding a new one.

It works fine but since the app is installed on a VM, when i close the remote desktop window and reopen it later, the collection behaviour changes. the size limit is no longer respected, and the observablecollection gets back to it's normal behaviour (no size limit). so if i had the maxsize to 5, i would have more than 5 items in the collection.
I'm not sure what is causing it.

here is the class i'm using to limit the size:

```
public class LimitedCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly int maxSize;
    public LimitedCollection(int maxSize)
    {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    new public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        if (Count == maxSize)
        {
            RemoveAt(maxSize - 1);

        }
            
        base.Insert(index, item);
    }
}
```

**Here is the method to read from the network and add the string in the collection**

```
private async Task<string> ReadMessage(TcpClient client, bool ownsClient)
    {
        
            using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

            int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
           
            Messages.Insert(0, message);
                         
            return message;
    

    }
```

**The xaml of the listbox bound to the ObservableCollection**

```
  <ScrollViewer  x:Name="NotamsTextBlockSv" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="NotamsTextBlockSv_PreviewMouseWheel">
            <ListBox x:Name="NotamsListBox"  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Messages}" Background="#FF0A0A0A" BorderBrush="#FFE0E0E0" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Foreground="#DDFFFFFF" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  >
                <!-- Remove interaction effects -->
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>

                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>

                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: How do you add new items to the collection?

Comment: You should override the [InsertItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.insertitem?view=net-7.0) method.

Comment: @KlausGütter i have edited my question and added the method that does the inserting in the collection.

Comment: @Clemens yes that's seems to be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Override `InsertItem` instead of hiding the `Insert` method:

```
public class LimitedCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly int maxSize;
    public LimitedCollection(int maxSize)
    {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (Count == maxSize)
        {
            RemoveAt(maxSize - 1);
            index--;
        }

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

The `InsertItem` method is called internally when you `Add` an item to the collection.

Given this implementation, there should be no "normal behaviour (no size limit)" for the `LimitedCollection<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had to remove `index--;` since i'm always inserting at the top of the collection(index =0). Now when i close the rdp session and get back i get this error **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index must be within the bounds of the List. (Parameter 'index')** but at least this time the maxsize is taken into account. I'm not  sure what happen to the collection afterwards. I have edited my question and added the method  that reads from the network and insert the string in the collection.

Comment: So what is your current question?